Is choosing B in an exam every time actually beneficial?
The title is fairly self explanatory. In exams where the right answer is a choice between $a,b,c$ and $d$, it feels like picking any of the options for every question has a better chance, versus randomly picking an answer each time. Is this actually true? Or would it just be a $\frac{1}{4}$ chance for every answer. It feels almost obvious that you would have a better chance by picking one for every answer.

Are you claiming that there is a bias in the distribution of correct answers?  Otherwise...well, each guess is a $\frac 14$ matter independent of all other guesses.

If the answers are assigned randomly, you are correct.  However, psychologically, perhaps the instructor is more likely to use $b$ for the correct answer.  Perhaps he read that a clueless student is most likely to choose $c$, so he avoids $c$.

If you flip a coin repeatedly and try to guess how it will turn up you will be right on average half the time no matter how you decide to make your guesses. Heads every time, alternating, random.
Your exam strategy will give the same probabilities in either case as long as the instructor decides at random where they will put the correct answer to each question.
